# Why would you ever use oil paint on new work?

Tags: paint, oil-based-paint

Background: a large steel door at our office was recently painted with an oil-based paint, and we spent the day suffering through the fumes that permeated practically every space in the building.

What are the advantages of using oil-based paint over a zero-VOC latex enamel? Does it key better to steel (the door was primed; I'm not sure with what)? Is it more durable? What other advantages does it have over other options?

Comment: They should have removed the door, and painted it in an unoccupied area.

Comment: Is this a question or just a rant?

Comment: Well, it's kind of both. I honestly didn't know why latex wouldn't be acceptable, but the tone of the post was definitely influenced by the headache induced by the solvent fumes. Anyway, I have my answer; latex won't stick to metal properly, AND the oil enamel will be more durable. Wish I could give them both the check.

Comment: @KeithS I removed the rant portion of the question to try to save it (it's got a few close votes right now). If you disagree, feel free to roll back my change.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Enamel paints hold better, are MUCH harder than latex, and will stand up to a lot more abuse. You can also use harsher cleaning methods on them.

Answer (score 18):

Latex paints won't bond properly to metal, it will flake, peel, and bubble off.

Comment: Understand that I only didn't give you the check because you already have 11k rep; gotta support the newer guys who also know stuff. :)

Comment: Now ain't that the wrong reason :/

Comment: Social justice has made its way to stackexchange...